# How do i define indexes for an entity map field with jpa/hibernate?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity that has a Map ElementCollection field. I know that with Jpa you can define indexes for regular fields using the @Index annotation on the class level. The problem is that my map element collection field creates a junction table that is not created by an @Entity annotated class. So I can't use the @Index annotations. Is there a Jpa/Hibernate way to define indexes for the fields in this junction table or will i have to define them manually? Heres the Map field.

```
@ElementCollection
@MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "language_id")
@CollectionTable(name="language_plantTypeNameTranslations",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="plantTypeNameTranslations_id"))
private Map<Language, String> plantTypeNameTranslations;
```

Thank you

Comment: The `@CollectionTable` has an `indexes` property...

Comment: @crizzis you're right! thanks allot man. Please make an answer from your comment so i can accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@CollectionTable` has an `indexes` property which works basically the same way `@Table.indexes` does.

As a side note, I'd seriously consider switching to a database version control tool like Liquibase or Flyway, especially for stuff like indexes. Indexes are not really part of the data model, they also come and go as the quality, quantity, and query requirements of the data changes in your db. Managing them using source code annotations renders them pretty inflexible.